# How does css scale transform affect document flow?

Tags: css, transform

I'm really confused how scaling an element using css transforms affects document flow.

[Consider this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ukaxef/2/edit) or [this codepen since jsbin seems to have gone down](http://codepen.io/anon/full/twGzE) where I have

```
p{slipsum text}
#scaled
  #scaled-content{some text}
p{slipsum text}
```

with the stylesheet

```
#scaled-contents {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  font-size: 3em;
}

#scaled {
  transform: scale(0.25, 0.25); //browser prefixes...
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}
```

I would expect this to show up similarly to a single 100x100 blue square. But it is shifted and on chrome even overlaps the following p element slightly. In addition, examining the dimensions of #scaled in devtools shows at as squat and long, seemingly breaking beyond it's 100x100 box.

Finally, adding `overflow: hidden;` to #scaled does something crazy altogether.

What is going on? How is content flow supposed to be affected?

Comment: Link is dead... Can we get a Fiddle?

Comment: @Mooseman - oh dammit, this was just alive a few minutes ago, I used it. Ok, got to rewrite everything

Comment: @Mooseman - updated with a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/full/twGzE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CSS Transform does not affect document flow. The DOM element will occupy it's original position and dimensions within the page flow.

So if you have 3 square div's of identical size, displayed inline in a row and apply a -webkit-transform: scale(2) to the center square, this square will scale up to 200% larger, scale from the center of its original position, and overlap both other squares.

Reference example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ypnEk/

HTML:

```
<div class="square one"></div>
<div class="square two"></div>
<div class="square three"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.square{
  margin-top:50px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.one{
  background:#222;
}

.two{
  background:#888;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
}

.three{
  background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on in my example then. If I scale an element AND set a height/width on it - is that scaling the element itself or just its contents? And why would stuff be overlapping with other elements then?

Comment: Issue with your example is: 1. The containing element is 100px x 100px, with a 400px square inside of it. As such, the blue square will overflow from that containing box. 2. The 25% scale you have on the containing element is scaling ALL contents of that box, but is scaling it from the center of the container. So, since you have effectively a container of 100px height with 300px of vertical overflow, the blue square will still sit outside the 100px containing element. Quick fix for your example is to add -prefix-transform-origin:0 0; to #scaled to force the scale down from the top left corner.

Comment: ahhh, `transform-origin` was the key that I was missing. That's what I wanted, not to translate