# Why float position Elements not move when the element scale down

Tags: javascript, html, css

All:

Say right now I have 3 DIVs sit in a same row, each is width: 33%; height:100%;
And right now I want to use transform: scale(0.5) to zoom out the first one, and I thought the second one will move left, but I do not know why the second one does not move at all, could anyone help?

Comment: Transforming an element does not change its original dimensions or position.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, any solution for this?

Comment: Instead, tweak its dimensions (height and width). You can even do it programmatically using `JavaScript` or `CSS` with animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14386948/5297207) and this quote from the accepted answer pretty much explains it:

> CSS Transform does not affect document flow. The DOM element will
>   occupy its original position and dimensions within the page flow.

*[Answer by chrisgonzalez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387069/5297207)*

So your DIV doesn't move because despite the scaling, the document still treats the element as being of its original size. To make the change affect flow you'll have to actually change its dimensions with width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use `transform` a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) will be created. In that case the object will act as a containing block for `position: fixed` elements that it contains.