# CSS Translate creates white space on original position

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to translate text but it creates space on original position and affects the following div label, when upperhide style is executed, the label remains left aligned but when upper style is used due to transformation it creates white space on its spot and label is right aligned.
I tried wrapping uppertext on div and translating it but dint solve white space issue. Any recommendations is greatly appreciated.
 Style and Html as follows,

```
  Upper:{
    transform: "translate(-4px, -20px) scale(.5)",
    backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF",
    transformOrigin:"top center",
    outline: "1px solid transparent",
    overflow:"hidden"

  },
  Upperhide:{
   display:'none'
  },
```

```
       <div id="Uppertext" className={(value) ? classes.Upper : classes.Upperhide}>{label}</div>
       <div id="Label" className={classes.Label}>{label}</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-field-4by3l
In the example code, the button contains hello as upper text. When translated it remains to occupy the original div spot, label appears only after the orginal div spot occupied by the upper text

Comment: Can you add codesandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `transform: translate()` does not alter the document flow. The element's original space is unaffected and still visible in it's original position. (Already discussed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387069/2311559)).

To accomplish what you want, you will need to use absolute positioning to take the element out of the document flow. So replace this:

```
transform: translate(-4px, -11px);
```

with this:

```
position: absolute;
left: -4px;
top: -11px;
```

(Also note the parent element - in this case the `<button>` - has to be positioned as well using either `position: relative` or `position: absolute`)

You can see a side by side comparison here:

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
span {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
.transform {
  transform: translate(-4px, -11px);
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="transform">This</span> is transformed
</button>

<button>
  <span class="absolute">This</span> is positioned
</button>
```

Comment: Well explained! Could you also share how rotation can be achieved in similar way.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can combine rotation and `position: absolute`. Add another line where you rotate without translating: `transform: rotate(45deg)`.